# Writing a Version Number Function in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I want to write a function that will give me the next version number for a table.  The table stores the existing version on each record. For example,
I have the cat table

**cats**

```
seqid    1
name     Mr Smith
version number  1.2b.3.4
```

How can I write a program that will be able to increment these values based on various conditions?

**This is my first attempt**

```
if v_username is not null
then v_new_nbr = substr(v_cur_nbr, 1,7)||to_number(substr(v_cur_nbr, 8,1))+1
```

should be `1.2b.3.5`

Comment: Hint : Google Sequences.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - do you really think that's a helpful suggestion? Especially as it seems likely the Seeker will want to maintain a monotonically incrementing version number for **each cat**?

Comment: I will be doing this in an Oracle database.

Comment: @pryorlaughs If you have control over the design of this table, I would break out the complex version number string into separate columns for it's component parts.  This way updating a particular part of the (now simple) version number is easy.  Reconstructing the version number from the component parts is easy using a virtual column or view.

Answer (score 2):

> `substr(v_cur_nbr, 1,7)||to_number(substr(v_cur_nbr, 8,1))+1`

This hurls `ORA-01722: invalid number`. The reason is a subtle one. It seems Oracle applies the concatenation operator before the additions, so effectively you're adding one to the string `'1.2b.3.4'`.

One solution is using a TO_CHAR function to bracket the addition with the second substring before concatenating the result with the first substring:

`substr(v_cur_nbr, 1,7) || to_char(to_number(substr(v_cur_nbr, 8,1))+1)`

Working demo on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=729093e4ddc56e952e2be615939e6f63).

---

Incidentally, a key like this is a bad piece of data modelling. Smart keys are dumb. They always lead to horrible SQL (as you're finding) and risk data corruption. A proper model would have **separate columns** for each element of the version number. We can use virtual columns to concatenate the version number for display circumstances.

```
create table cats(
seqid    number
,name     varchar2(32)
,major_ver_no1 number
,major_ver_no2 number
,variant varchar2(1)
,minor_ver_no1 number
,minor_ver_no2 number
,v_cur_nbr  varchar2(16) generated always as (to_char(major_ver_no1,'FM9') ||'.'||
                                              to_char(major_ver_no2,'FM9')  ||'.'||
                                              variant  ||'.'||
                                              to_char(minor_ver_no1,'FM9')  ||'.'||
                                              to_char(minor_ver_no2,'FM9') ) );
```

So the set-up is a bit of a nause but incrementing the version numbers is a piece of cake.

```
update cats
set major_ver_no1 = major_ver_no1 +1 
    , major_ver_no2 = 0
    , variant = 'a';
```

There's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f47ceac0ba84cc67a8cf7234966360f) for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Try searching mask for [TO_NUMBER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_2117.htm#OLADM695) to be able to get the decimal number, this small example might help:

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table (version varchar2(100));
INSERT INTO tmp_table(version) VALUES ('1.2b.3.4');
DECLARE
    mainVersion NUMBER;
    subVersion  NUMBER;
    currentVersion VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
    SELECT version INTO currentVersion FROM tmp_table;
    mainVersion := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(currentVersion,1,3),'9.9') + 0.1;
    subVersion  := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(currentVersion,6,3),'9.9') + 1.1;
    UPDATE tmp_table SET version = (mainVersion||'b.'||subVersion);
END;
```

Comment: Thank you for this info!