# Incrementing and comparing version in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, version, increment

I want to do the following

- 1a.0.0.0 should come before 18.9.3.1 in a sort
- 1a.0.0.0 should come first
- Increment by 1 in any numeric value
- Increment by alphabet any alpha numeric value
- Select the max version by correct sort

create table revision_table
(revision_nbr varchar2(30))

```
REVISION_NBR
1.0.0.0
1.2.0.1
18.9.3.1
1a.0.0.0
20.2.0.0
20a.2.0.0
```

Comment: Hi @pryorlaughs , what database do you use, what is your expected result, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: @VBoka, it is an Oracle database.  If I have a version 19.8.2 how do I get it to go to 19.9.0?

Comment: I do not believe you always want it to  increment in this way?

Comment: If you had followed [my advice on your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60043932/146325) you wouldn't be stuck like this. Messy so-called smart keys are very hard to sort because they are alphanumeric: `11.2.99` comes before `2.0.0`. "incrementing" `20a.2` to `20b.2` requires special rules. And what happens when you want to go `21.0`? There is no standard way to do this, because it's not something people should try to do. Follow 1st Normal Form. Use atomic columns. Increment columns. Sort by columns.  Concatenate for display.

Comment: Every time you want to increment a version number you must break down the string into its component parts, determine the datatype of the element you wish to increment, maybe cast it to a number, apply the incrementing logic, then concatenate it back into a string. Every time you want to sort by version number, you must break the string into its component parts, determine the datatype of the element you wish to increment, maybe cast it to a number, for **each component in the string**.  `20a.2.0.0` has five components to sort separately. `20a.2b.0.0` has six. Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Well this sounds like a "[Fool's errand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool%27s_errand)", if not just a bad design.   
First lets give version a format definition.

- Let Version, denoted by V, be composed of levels, denoted by L, separated by single dots, ( V -> L1.L2. ... Ln)
- Let each level be composed of a mandatory string of digits, denoted by Lnd, and an option string of lower case English letters a though z, denoted by Lns.  

  With the definition is hand sort the version list on L1d, L1s,L2d, L2s ... Lnd, Lds. Where omitted Lns values sort to the end of list for a given Ln.

The following SQL performs the requested sort for N=4.

```
with versions as 
   (select '1.2.3.4'  v  from dual union all
    select '1.0.0.0'     from dual union all
    select '1.2.0.1'     from dual union all
    select '1.10.0.1'    from dual union all    
    select '18.9.3.1'    from dual union all
    select '1a.0.0.0'    from dual union all
    select '1b.0.0.0'    from dual union all    
    select '20.2.0.0'    from dual union all    
    select '20a.2.0.0'   from dual union all
    select '1az.0.0.0'   from dual union all     
    select '1a.2b.3c.4d' from dual 
   )  
select v
  from versions
 order by  
       to_number(regexp_replace(replace(regexp_substr(v,'(\d+)([a-z]*)(\.|$)',1,1 ) ,'.',null),'(\d+)([a-z]*)','\1') )
     , regexp_replace(replace(regexp_substr(v,'(\d+)([a-z]*)(\.|$)',1,1 ) ,'.',null),'(\d+)([a-z]*)','\2') 
     , to_number(regexp_replace(replace(regexp_substr(v,'(\d+)([a-z]*)(\.|$)',1,2 ) ,'.',null),'(\d+)([a-z]*)','\1') )
     , regexp_replace(replace(regexp_substr(v,'(\d+)([a-z]*)(\.|$)',1,2 ) ,'.',null),'(\d+)([a-z]*)','\2')  
     , to_number(regexp_replace(replace(regexp_substr(v,'(\d+)([a-z]*)(\.|$)',1,3 ) ,'.',null),'(\d+)([a-z]*)','\1') )
     , regexp_replace(replace(regexp_substr(v,'(\d+)([a-z]*)(\.|$)',1,3 ) ,'.',null),'(\d+)([a-z]*)','\2')  
     , to_number(regexp_replace(replace(regexp_substr(v,'(\d+)([a-z]*)(\.|$)',1,4 ) ,'.',null),'(\d+)([a-z]*)','\1') )
     , regexp_replace(replace(regexp_substr(v,'(\d+)([a-z]*)(\.|$)',1,4 ) ,'.',null),'(\d+)([a-z]*)','\2')        
;
```

So that takes care of ***The easy Part*** correctly(?) sorting. To increment versions defines a function with the following parameters:
The version to increment  (V), 
The Level to Increment   (Ln),
The Part of the Level to Increment  (Lnd) or (Lns)

In addition to just upping the indicated value for parameters what needs to be done for the currently undefined actions.

- When incrementing Lns and the letter is already 'z'.
- When incrementing Lnd and Lns exists is keep or drop Lns.
- How to increment Lnd + Lns to just Lnd (ie 1a. to 1.)  

  You really don't want to do this but if you try well echoing @APC: Good luck with that.